# error: field ‘m_ssmmap’ has incomplete type C++

Tags: c++

I have the following header file.

```
#ifndef __ROUTERPIM__
#define __ROUTERPIM__

#include "AbstractRouterVRF.h"

class VRF;
class SSMMap;

class RouterPim: public AbstractRouterVRF{
    private:
            string m_rp_address;
            unsigned int m_hello_timer;
            SSMMap m_ssmmap;   //>> line of error
    public:
            RouterPim();
            RouterPim(VRF *vrf);
            virtual ~RouterPim();
            void setrp_address(string rp_address);
            void sethello_timer(unsigned int hello_timer);
            string getrp_address();
            unsigned int gethello_timer();
            static RouterPim* instantiateRouterPim(VRF *vrf);
            virtual string getclass_name();
            virtual void dump();
            virtual int validation(DCMENUMS *attr, void *new_value);
            virtual int update(DCMENUMS *attr, void *value);
            static string getAttributeStr(int attr);
};

#endif /* __ROUTERPIM__ */
```

While compiling, it is giving the following error at line 13.

```
`RouterPim.h:13:10: error: field ‘m_ssmmap’ has incomplete type`
`SSMMap m_ssmmap;`
      ^
```

when I comment out line 13, it just compiles fine. Can anyone point me what is the issue here? Why the same problem is not seen for external class `VRF` which is also being used exactly the same way as `SSMMap` class.

Comment: You have only forward declared `SSMMap`.  To decare `SSMMap m_ssmmap` the compiler need to know how much space to allocate.  To do this is needs to see its full definition.

Comment: Interesting to point on the difference between `SSMMap` and `VRF` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler wants to automatically instantiate the object of class `SSMMap` because you embedded it *by value*. But it cannot find the constructor for it. A forward declaration like

```
class SSMMap;
```

allows only to declare pointers (or references) of that type. In your case, you have to use

```
SSMMap* m_ssmmap;
```

or alternatively

```
SSMMap& m_ssmmap;
```

But then you have to take care of construction and destruction in the corresponding cpp file. This technique is often called PIMPL idiom (which means *pointer to implementation*).

The other option you have is to include the definition of `SSMMap` which is probably already done in a header file.

> the same problem is not seen for external class VRF

it's not the same problem, because `VRF` is not used by value, but as a pointer instead. (Even if you use a `VRF` object as value for a parameter, it's not the same, because the *signature* of that function can be created with that information: only when calling the function, the type must be complete.)

Comment: Thanks much. That clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You only *declared* `SSMMap` (more specifically: *forward declarared*):

```
class SSMMap; //Forward declaration
```

The compiler requires a *definition* of `SSMMap`, which it doesn't find, and so it complains.

You'll need to `#include` the header where the definition of `SSMMap` is located.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this in two ways:

1. change it to a pointer, that way it won't need the specification of the class: `SSMMap *m_ssmmap;`
2. include the SSMMap header file instead of the line: class SSMMap;